# How to Sort String numbers using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

This is my data `["2","1","10"]`. When I am trying to sort these numbers my output is `["1","10","2"]`, but my expected output is `["1","2","10]` . I am using orderBy to sort these numbers. It sorts depending upon 0 to 9 only.

How can I sort these numbers using js?

Here is my code:

```
ng-options="option.id as option.roomno for option in frData 
          | unique:'roomno' | orderBy:'roomno' "
```

Comment: `["2","1","10"].sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});`

Comment: iterate and take parseInt of each element and sort.. finally convert it toString

Comment: You parse the strings as numbers when comparing, but you're not being very clear on how you're sorting them, should we assume you're using Angular, if so, tag correctly.

Comment: Is that all the code? Missing an Angular tag, maybe? Anyway, alphabetically 10 comes before 2 of course, so you either will have to treat the values as numbers when sorting, or left-pad them with zeros.

Comment: Use the `.sort()` method to sort arrays. [source](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp)

Comment: @Rayon , Can yu pls explain me your code ! a,b and return a-b .. What is the functionality here ?

Comment: @SaravanaKumar — You are suppose to read about [__`Array#sort`__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: 1. Convert String to an Integer  2. Sort  3. Convert Integer to String

Comment: @ABUdhay , I having some string alphabets also so how can i find out difference between string numbers and Alphabets ?

Comment: @DineshKanivu , answer for my above comment buddy :)

Comment: @Rayon, Got it thank yu

Comment: buddy your requirement was sorting  ["2","1","10"] , and if you have to sort string sorry Buddy I might think

Comment: Have a look at this link. It explains the sort function with examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202616/difference-between-sort-sortfunctiona-breturn-a-b-and-sortfunctiona/39208684#39208684

Comment: @Setily, Thanks  . that was really helpful .

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortNumStr(m,n) {
    return m - n;
}

var numArray = ["2", "1", "10"];
numArray.sort(sortNumStr);
alert(numArray)
```

Comment: _Clarification:_ `return m - n;` determines the sorting to be _ascending_, if you use `return n - m;` it determines the sorting to be _descending_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string's native prototype `localeCompare` function like so:

```
["2","1","10"].sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, undefined, { numeric: true }))
```

It works well with numbers among other chars too.